# Half planes, shaded unbounded regions

Tags: tikz-pgf

What ways do you use to sketch unbounded regions in $\mathbb{R}^{2};$
[image: $y\geq-x$]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan!50]      (-4,4) -| (4,-4) -- cycle;
\draw[cyan, thick]  (-4,4) -- (4,-4);
% axis, on the top
\draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```